# IE Mode in Edge supported by IEDriver not able to automate

Tags: java, windows, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

since internet Explore is depreciated nowadays we have switched to edge browser but like you some sites support ie browser instead of edge so I need to run ie mode in edge browser here is an example of my code:

IE Mode in Edge supported by IEDriver

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\\Automation\\Jar Details\\Drivers\\edgedriver.exe");
     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Automation\\Jar Details\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    // System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\ofoxborn\\Desktop\\IE_Edge\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        InternetExplorerDriverService ieService = InternetExplorerDriverService.createDefaultService();

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setAcceptInsecureCerts(false);
        caps.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
        caps.setCapability("ie.edgechromium", true);
        System.out.println("caps.getBrowserName() = " + caps.getBrowserName());
        System.out.println("caps browserName = " + caps.getCapability("browserName"));
        caps.setCapability("ie.edgepath", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");

        InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        options.enablePersistentHovering();
        options.ignoreZoomSettings();
        options.requireWindowFocus();
        options.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieService, options.merge(caps));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://github.com");

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("caps.getBrowserName() = " + caps.getBrowserName());
        System.out.println("caps browserName = " + caps.getCapability("browserName"));

        driver.quit();
    }
```

I don't know about it but when I run this the ie got invoked and run successfully I want it to start an edge browser I am using selenium 4.0.0 jar file and my ie version 10 is there something.
i am using ie driver 4.0.0
And so i done with setting in edge brwoser[This is edge browser seeting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4jlS.png) is there any window realted seeting i am misssing please help me and Thanks in advance

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tested the problem and I think it is reasonable. In the official documentation it is stated that if you need to use Edge IE mode, one of the prerequisites is to enable IE11. Just refer to this doc: [Edge IE mode-Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#prerequisites).

And as far as I know, IEdriver will start any version of IE installed in the machine, when Edge IE mode conditions are not met, it will not lanuch Edge, but default Internet Explorer.

So you could upgrade the version of IE to 11. I think this should make it work.